# Any efficient way to filter out multi-dim dataframe by measuring its correlation coefficient in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I intend to find Pearson correlation coefficient from multi-dim data to one numeric vector in R. Basically, I am expecting to get a correlation matrix by using the Pearson method, want to keep the rows (a.k.a, features for each column) in multi-dim data by using certain correlation coefficient as threshold.However, I tentatively tried some R implementation to do that but didn't get correct correlation matrix though. How can I get this one? can anyone point me out how to make this happen easily in R? any thought?

**reproducible example**

```
persons_df <- data.frame(person1=sample(1:20,10, replace = FALSE),
                    person2=as.factor(sample(10)),
                    person3=sample(1:25,10, replace = FALSE),
                    person4=sample(1:30,10, replace = FALSE),
                    person5=as.factor(sample(10)),
                    person6=as.factor(sample(10)))

row.names(persons_df) <-letters[1:10]
```

in `persons_df`, different features in row-wise and different persons in column-wise are given.

I have also `age_df` which has age of each person.

```
age_df <- data.frame(personID= colnames(persons_df),
                     age=sample(1:50, 6 , replace = FALSE))
```

**my initial attempt**:

```
pearson_corr <- function(df1, df2, verbose=FALSE){
    stopifnot(ncol(df1)==nrow(df2))
    res <- as.data.frame()
    lapply(colnames(df1), function(x){
        lapply(x, rownames(y){
            if(colnames(x) %in% rownames(df2)){
                cor_mat <- stats::cor(y, df2$age, method = "pearson")
                ncor <- ncol(cor_mat)
                cmatt <- col(cor_mat)
                ord <- order(-cmat, cor_mat, decreasing = TRUE)- (ncor*cmatt - ncor)
                colnames(ord) <- colnames(cor_mat)
                res <- cbind(ID=c(cold(ord), ID2=c(ord)))
                res <- as.data.frame(cbind(out, cor=cor_mat[res]))
                res <- cbind(res, cor=cor_mat[out])
            }
        })
    })
    return(final_df)
}
```

but above code didn't return correct correlation matrix. what I want to do how each features of the certain person is correlated with his age. Is there any efficient way to make this happen? any idea?

**goal:**

basically, I want to keep the features which show a high correlation with age. I don't have a better idea to do this in R. Can anyone point me out how to get his done easily and efficiently in R? thanks

Comment: An example of your expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = do.call(rbind,
                 apply(persons_df, 1, function(x){
                     temp = cor.test(age_df$age, as.numeric(x))
                     data.frame(t = temp$statistic, p = temp$p.value)
                 }))
mylist
#           t            p
#a  -1.060264 3.488012e-01
#b  -2.292612 8.361623e-02
#c -16.785311 7.382895e-05
#d  -1.362776 2.446304e-01
#e  -1.922296 1.269356e-01
#f  -4.671259 9.509393e-03
#g  -3.719296 2.048710e-02
#h  -2.684663 5.496171e-02
#i -15.814635 9.341701e-05
#j  -2.423014 7.252635e-02
```

Then use `mylist` to filter out what values you don't want.